# What is the weight of a column of NULLS in parquet?

Tags: parquet

If I have a column of only null values in parquet, what is the order of magnitude of its weight. 
Is it going to be of the order 1,  size of the columns . or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The weight should be O(1). Nulls are encoded with definition levels, which are run-length-encoded. You can prove this to yourself by writing such a file from Python

```
In [1]: import pyarrow.parquet as pq                                                           

In [2]: import pyarrow as pa                                                                   

In [3]: t = pa.table([pa.array([None] * 10000000)], ['a'])                                     

In [4]: pq.write_table(t, 'all_nulls.parquet')                                                 

In [5]: !ls -l all_nulls*                                                                      
-rw------- 1 wesm wesm 391 Dec  9 06:35 all_nulls.parquet
```

So a table with a column of 10 million nulls takes up 391 bytes all told (mostly metadata I'd guess...)